# objectbox go undefined: objectbox.ObjectBox

Tags: go, objectbox

I am new to GO and to objectbox. I am on Windows 10.
My version of GO is

```
go version go1.20.1 windows/amd64
```

I am using Visual Studio 1.77.3

I am working through the demo at

https://golang.objectbox.io/getting-started

when I declared the import of

```
"github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox"
```

the IDE downloaded the dependency for me.

I copy/paste the function initObjectBox as

```
func initObjectBox() *objectbox.ObjectBox {
    objectBox, err := objectbox.NewBuilder().Model(model.ObjectBoxModel()).Build()
    return objectBox
}
```

and when I am done, the IDE has underlines on objectbox.ObjectBox and objectbox.NewBuilder that says

```
undefined: objectbox.ObjectBox
undefined: objectbox.NewBuilder
```

The IDE knows about objectbox, when I shift-click the word objectbox it takes me to the import declaration in my code:

```
"github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox"
```

When I shift-click that import it takes me to

```
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go@v1.7.0
```

Thinking this must be my fault, I instead download the objectbox project

```
git clone https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go
```

when I open that I find

```
examples/tasks/main.go
```

which looks very much like the getting-started example. This code shows the same error for every single dot property of objectbox except objectBox.Close

```
undefined: objectbox.ObjectBox
undefined: objectbox.NewBuilder
undefined: objectbox.SyncIsAvailable
undefined: objectbox.SyncCredentialsNone
undefined: objectbox.SyncChange
```

When I try to run the app in GO I get the errors described in

https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/issues/17

I have installed TDM-GCC-64 and I have run the install.ps1 script from https://golang.objectbox.io/install#windows which downloaded objectbox.dll to

```
C:\TDM-GCC-64\lib\objectbox.dll
```

The objectbox dll also got copied to my

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

I ran the tdm-gcc insaller at

```
https://github.com/jmeubank/tdm-gcc/releases/download/v10.3.0-tdm64-2/tdm64-gcc-10.3.0-2.exe
```

and my path contains

```
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin
```

my GOPATH is

```
go env
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\Dave\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\Dave\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.20.1
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
set GOMOD=C:\projects\gogo\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1594667240=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was preparing all the information above to create the best possible question, I wondered if the windows path addition

```
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin
```

was updated after I started Visual Studio. I shut down Visual Studio and re-started it and opened my example project and it ran perfectly. There are no errors in the IDE and the command line ran main.go without issue. I was using the Visual Studio console to run the command line, so even the command line issues were caused by this path problem. The error messages were very un-intuitive and not previously addressed in SO.

Comment: trying this all from scratch on a new computer, ran into the same error, found this post, and the path was not the problem this time. even though there was a file
C:\TDM-GCC-64\lib\objectbox.dll that was not what was on the path, the install script added C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin to the path. I dropped the dll into C:\Windows\System32 as I did before and it is running. The dll not being in the path is a bug in the objectbox install.ps1 script for setting up on Windows.